# Tor Detection IP Address different then other websites, help

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, ip-address

**Help Help Help**First question... In Parrot Security when I have both the Tor Browser connected and Anonsurf why do I have two different IP addresses.  When I am in the browser and go to what is my IP address it gives me one address and when I click on the button in Anonsurf My IP address it gives me another IP address.  How is this possible.  Don't you only have one IP address at a time.  They are both IPv4 addresses so I am not confusing the two.  I just don't understand how you can have two different IP addresses on the same computer without running a virtual machine or something.  If anyone can Help with this part I would appreciate it.

Second question, when I start Anonsurf in Parrot and open up a regular browser and go to a webpage where am I.  It gives my current location.  I thought Anonsurf routes all traffic through Tor.

Lastly when I was using Tor and went to the Tor Detection website I got one IP address and when I went to another site at the same time (what is my IP address) it gave me another IP address it was similar but not the same, IDK if it was some kind of mess up or what.  If anyone knows why that could happen, I would appreciate it, explaining it to me.  Thnaks.

Answer (score 1):

First, a device (your PC) can have multiple IP addresses, even on one physical interface. But that's not the thing with tor.

When using tor, the address shown is not yours, but the one of the exit node you are using in that moment for that circuit.

Simply said, you are using a new circuit for every site you visit so everytime, new address. In tor browser you can click left of the address bar and get the info, which nodes are active for that site. In another tab, another circuit, usually, another address.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can have multiple *outbound* addresses shown by an external sites because of Tor's feature to use a separate authentication user as a separated pipe, i.e. it will go out through another chain and - most likely - through another Exit Node. If you have Tor on your PC - basically you don't need anything else, everything can be configured using a standard system tools. Anonsurf is not needed when you're using just a Tor Browser - it's an overkill and it can make your work slower **without** adding any security

Comment: I also was curious about one other thing.  In parrot Sec. when I open the GUI for Anonsurf and look at the Tor Stats while it is running then open a normal firefox browser.  Anon says "there has been an application request to port 80 which is commonly used for sending unencrypted data.  Don't send anything that you wouldnt mind the rest of the internet reading."  Should I be seeing this since all internet traffic is supposed to be going through Tor?  Or does this mean something needs to be looked at?

Comment: Firefox might check for updates over normal http.